# How to remove the Live Share button?

Tags: layout, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-liveshare

I've installed Visual Studio 2019 and the first thing that annoys me is the large black, empty space on top of the screen after removing all my toolbars.

The 'Live Share' and 'Feedback' button don't show up as toolbars though.

[image]

Is there a way to reclaim the whitespace by removing those two buttons?

Comment: it might help to know which edition you use. community or enterprise ?

Comment: The one in between: VS Professional (16.0.0)

Comment: Using the Community edition and the problem is the same

Comment: i am using the community edition as well and i don't have this problem, maybe resetting the visual-studio settings will solve this for you

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/516307/cannot-reclaim-toolbar-space-after-removing-all-to.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can hide the Live Share and Feedback buttons area with Visual Commander: https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2019/03/19/freeing-screen-space-in-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: Tried and this works. Great work, VS looks a lot nicer with the extra whitespace.

Comment: This seems to the only solution that actually works. I'll accept it. Thanks for writing the extension.

Comment: Enabling this in VS2019 hid all of my other toolbars. I just wanted to remove Live Share.

Comment: @drescherjm Please note there are two extensions: "Hide Live Share and Feedback in VS 2019.vcmd" hides Live Share and "Hide Live Share and Feedback in VS 2019 plus toolbars area.vcmd" hides the toolbars area. You need the first one.

Comment: I see. I downloaded the wrong one. Thank you.

Answer (score 43):

Uninstall the **Live Share** feature via Visual Studio Installer under individual components

[image]

Now the button is gone.

Comment: We need to remove the button taking valuable toolbar space, not the "feature"

Comment: Not a bad idea but it still leaves the 'feedback' button so the whitespace remains.

Comment: The feedback button has nothing to do with Live Share. If you want to remove that, it's a different issue from removing the Live Share button. The title of this question is "How to remove the Live Share button?" This answer works.

Comment: Not available as a choice in the Installer of v.16.9.0 anymore.

Comment: @MikeKaganski ok, in this case disable the extension in extension dialog. Does this work?

Comment: @magicandre1981: as I mentioned in a comment to the answer by Hamid Baghernia, it does. My comment here was to add information to *this* answer (which does not work anymore with newer VS version(s)).

Answer (score 36):

You just need to go to Extensions -> Manage Extensions, look for Live Share, and disable it.

Comment: The question is about VS 2019. This answer presents the VS 2019 native solution w/o any third-party extensions. This is the answer that should be accepted.

Comment: Actually, the OP wants to "reclaim the whitespace by removing those two buttons" not disable Live Share so the accepted solution is the best answer. I did wanted to disable Live Share so this answer did helped me.

Comment: I confirm, works in VS 2019 to completly disable Live Share. Thanks

Comment: ... and VS 2019 v.16.9.0 removed LiveShare from its individual components in VS Installer, so disabling it in the Extension Manager seems to the only built-in method still working.

Comment: Normally this does work to hide the Live Share button in the toolbar, however my VS just auto-restarted after crashing due to some COM error (i.e. VS itself got corrupted) and **even though** the Live Share extension is disabled, the button now appears in the top-right corner (clicking it does nothing). Grrr.

Comment: This is a better, quicker solution than a complete uninstall of the LiveShare feature. This allows for a quicker reactivation of LiveShare whenever that may be desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, `disabling and restarting` no longer removes LiveShare for me. Not sure if  there are other extensions that affect this. Requires uninstall.

Comment: Same here as ToolmakerSteve. When I disable the extension, the LiveShare button is still there, and clicking it throws an error about 'CascadePackage' package did not load correctly. I don't use LiveShare so I'm going with magicandre1981's answer. Sergey Vlasov's answer would be fine too.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has been kind enough to fix it in the 16.2 version.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-version-16-2-generally-available-and-16-3-preview-1/

Comment: The key sentence from that link is *"Upon hiding all toolbars, the Live Share, Feedback and Badge icons are moved to the top."*

Comment: This is only for Preview version not for current VS 2019

Answer (score 0):

Go to extension installer or manger then search live share audio.
You need to uninstall live share audio first then uninstall live share server or any live share extension.
As all dependent on live share audio extension, if this removed rest can easily removed.

Comment: this removes the live share button and stops the live share service from running in the background